# Сложное предложение вместо вставных конструкций со скобками

Tags: скобки

Какими знаками препинания можно заменить скобки в приведённом диалоге? Тире?

– Интересно… – улыбнулся Николя (он стал потихоньку осваиваться).
– Я, наконец, развёлся с Лилиан, и…
– …и правильно сделал! – закончил за сына Николя. – Эта стерва мне никогда не нравилась! – Он недовольно сложил руки на груди (волнение прошло, Николя наконец-то стал
собой).

Answer (score 1):

> Какими знаками препинания можно заменить скобки в приведённом диалоге?
> Тире?

Как вариант – после «на груди» поставить точку и начать предложение «Волнение прошло…» с нового абзаца.

> – Интересно… – улыбнулся Николя (он стал потихоньку осваиваться).
>
> – Я, наконец, развёлся с Лилиан, и…
>
> – И правильно сделал! – закончил за сына Николя. – Эта стерва мне
> никогда не нравилась! – Он недовольно сложил руки на груди.
>
> Волнение прошло, Николя наконец-то стал собой.

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!